# Node.js, mysql and socket.io

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I am new with socket.io. I have a problem. How can I display real-time data from table from database without resetting node.js server. I have a new data in table in 10 seconds.

I tried some tutorials, but still have a problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. You can use websocket to communicate changes back to client over the wire but the question as currently written is too broad to be answered here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like this:

```js
const sendDataCycle = async() => {
  try {
    const data = await getData() // get data from DB
    io.send(data) // send by socket.io
    setTimeout(() => {
      sendDataCycle() // send again after 10 s
    }, 10000)
  } catch (err) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      sendDataCycle() // if error - send again after 20 s or else
    }, 20000)
  }
}

sendDataCycle() // run cycle
```

And please, don't use the `setInterval` function.